# On the topic of Trinomial Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was looking at the Wikipedia of the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) when I read this:

> #### Multi-binomial theorem
>
> When working in more than two dimensions, it is often useful to deal with products of binomial expansions. By the binomial theorem this is equal to
>
> $$(x_1+y_1)^{n_1}\cdots(x_d+y_d)^{n_d}=\sum_{k_1=0}^{n_1}\cdots\sum_{k_d=0}^{n_d}\binom{n_1}{k_1}x_1^{k_1}y_1^{n_1-k_1}\cdots\binom{n_d}{k_d}x_d^{k_d}y_d^{n_d-k_d}$$

Now say I wanted to write out $(a+b+c)^n$ in this way. Would I use this theorem to write it out as$$\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^r\dfrac{n!a^{n-r}b^{r-s}c^s}{s!(n-r)!(r-s)!}$$which would be gotten from$$(a+b+c)^n$$$$=(a+d)^n,d=b+c$$$$=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nra^{n-r}d^r$$$$=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nra^{n-r}(b+c)^r$$$$=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nra^{n-r}\sum_{s=0}^r\binom rsb^{r-s}c^s$$$$=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^r\dfrac{n!a^{n-r}b^{r-s}c^s}{s!(n-r)!(r-s)!}$$or how would I write out trinomial expansion?

---

##### To clarify

---

1. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288482/trinomial-expansion) question is different from my question that I am asking because it is asking more for a conjecture of the relation between the sum of the $2m$th powers of the diagonals of a regular $n$-gon and $n$, as mentioned by the OP of the question in a comment on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/288487/1160540) answer to the question.

Comment: You could also get a result with $(n-r-s)!$ in the denominator by switching $a,b,c$. [This article](https://sahilmohnani.wordpress.com/tag/trinomial/) verifies your result.

Comment: You can write a lot of things a lot of different ways.  The easiest thing you can do for a trinomial in my opinion is to just use the result of the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: I don't see any issues with what you've done here. You may also be interested in the multinomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: There's a nice brief write-up on the [trinomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion) in particular too.

Comment: In the reference given by @Sammy Black see in particular "Pascal pyramid".