# Trinomial Expansion question: $(x+y+z)^3=18$ where $x+y=z-xy$ and $y+z=xy+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was bored, so I decided to look back at my questions and noticed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702521/on-the-topic-of-trinomial-expansion) question of mine asking about trinomial expansion which I thought "hey, what if I created a piecewise equation using trinomial expansion", which made me come up with this:$$
\color{white}{.=}
\begin{cases}
(x+y+z)^3 & =18 \\
x+y & =z-xy \\
y+z & =xy+y
\end{cases}
$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the piecewise equation:

Since I know that$$x+y=z-xy$$and$$y+z=xy+y$$$$\therefore z=xy$$$$\therefore x+y=xy-xy$$$$\therefore x+y=0$$$$\implies x=-y,y=-x$$Also, since we know that $z^3=18,z=\sqrt[3]{18}$, therefore$$(x+y+\sqrt[3]{18})^3=18$$therefore$$(0+\sqrt[3]{18})^3=18$$and therefore$$x=y=0,z=\sqrt[3]{18}$$However, this is incorrect. Why? Because $0\neq\sqrt[3]{18}$ and $\sqrt[3]{18}\neq0+0$

---

---

#### My second attempt

---

---

$$x+\require{cancel}\cancel{y}-\cancel{y}-z=z-xy-xy-y$$$$x-z=z-2xy-y$$$$x-\cancel{z}+\cancel{z}=2z-2xy-y$$$$\therefore x=2z-2xy-y$$$$y=x-2z+2xy$$$$z=x-z+2xy-y$$Then plugging this into $x+y=z-xy$, we get$$x+y=x-z+2xy-y-8xyz+4x^2y^2+2x^2-2xy^2+2y^2-2xz-xy+4z^2$$However, this was beginning to get extremely complicated for me, so I decided to plug it into Wolfram Alpha which gave me these results [(all complex)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%29x%2By%2Bz%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%3D18%5C%2844%29x%2By%3Dz-xy%5C%2844%29y%2Bz%3Dxy%2By)

---

---

#### My question

---

---

What could I do to attain the correct solution, since it seems I was unable to do so myself?

Comment: Firstly you should get three solutions to the equation $z^3=18$, not just one. The other two are complex. Secondly $x+y=0$ does not imply $x=y=0$. When you have your $z$ values, use $z=xy\implies z=-x^2$ to find $x$ and $y$

Comment: From the third equation, $ z = xy $.  Substituting this into the second equation, $x + y = 0$.  Substituting this into the first equation $z^3 = 18$.  This is straight forward to solve.